# What is this weather stripping for a metal door called?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

The weather stripping on the metal door into my workshop has deteriorated and I’d like to replace it. It looks like there are two pieces that slide into a track but I’ve not been able to find it at any hardware store and I don’t know what to search for online.

This is on both the top and bottom of the door and I need to replace both.

What kind of weather stripping am I looking for?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's odd to have that on top. On the bottom it would be a "sweep", and they're usually proprietary, so hardware store replacements may not work right. You have to have the right rib configuration, height, etc. or they'll either leave a gap or drag too hard or fall off.

Try to get replacements from the manufacturer, or consider forgoing the top one and installing jamb seals instead.